# Laravel 5 form request

Tags: request, laravel-5

When I handle a CREATE post form, i'll do :

```
public function handlecreer(Requests\CreerUtilisateurRequest $request)
 {
    // handle create form 
            // all fields in one line... YEAH !!!
    $user = new User($request->except('password','role'));
    $user->password = bcrypt(Request::input('password'));
    $user->save();
....}
```

But if I have an UPDATE post form I'll do :

```
public function handleUpdate(Requests\UpdateUtilisateurRequest $request)
 {
    // handle update form
    $user = User::findOrFail(Request::input('id'));// find

       // one line by field... BOH !!!
    $user->name     = Request::input('name');
    $user->email    = Request::input('email');
    $user->password = bcrypt(Request::input('password'));
    $user->telephone= Request::input('telephone');
    $user->fonction = Request::input('fonction');
    $user->divers   = Request::input('divers');

    $user->save();
....}
```

Is there a simplest way of processing the update post form ?

Thanks,

Paguemaou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All mass assignable attributes (the one in `$fillable`) can be set using `fill()`:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(Request::input('id'));

$user->fill($request->except('password', 'role'));
$user->password = bcrypt(Request::input('password'));

$user->save();
```